# Evaluating predicate on binary strings

Tags: strings, bit-manipulation

Consider two *unknown* binary strings $$X = x_{1} x_{2} \dots x_{n^{2}}, \quad Y = y_{1} y_{2} \dots y_{n^{2}}, \quad x_{i}, y_{i} \in \{0, 1\} .$$ We may request a string $Z = z_{1} z_{2} \dots z_{n^{2}}$, where $z_{i} = x_{i}$ or $z_{i} = y_{i}$, no more than $n + 1$ times. So, for every request we set required $z_{i}$ (that is, $x_{i}$ or $y_{i}$) for every $i$.

Moreover, we have $n$ bits of unwritable memory, namely, every bit of that memory is set once and then does not change. This memory is avaliable all the time, but requested $Z$ strings drop out before the next request, so, we don't have complete list of all requested $Z$ strings.

The problem is to check if $X = Y$ with given $n$ bits and $n + 1$ times for $Z$ string request.

There is an extra question: is it possible to use $\mathcal{O}(\log^{2}(n))$ bits of memory and $\mathcal{O}(\log(r))$ requests.

I don't really understand area of CS that is closely related to the problem, could anyone give a hint?

Comment: I can't understand the sentence beginning "We may request a string $Z$". Do you mean: "We may make up to $n+1$ queries, where each query consists of a string of $n^2$ letters, each of which is either 'X' or 'Y'; the response to a query consists of a string of $n^2$ bits, with the $i$-th bit in the response set to $x_i$ if the $i$-th letter in the query is 'X', and instead set to $y_i$ if the $i$-th letter in the query is 'Y'."?

Comment: @j_random_hacker yes, every query is determined by string over $\{X, Y\}$, where each letter corresponds to unknown string from which the digit will be taken, and we may make up to $n + 1$ such queries.

Comment: OK.  That helps.  Can you please edit the question accordingly, so people can understand what you are asking without having to read the comments?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can think of $X,Y$ as $n\times n$ matrices with rows $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ and $b_1,\ldots,b_n$, respectively. Then $X = Y$ iff
$$
a_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus a_n = b_1 \oplus a_2 \oplus \cdots \oplus a_n = b_1 \oplus b_2 \oplus a_3 \oplus \cdots \oplus a_n = \cdots = b_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus b_n.
$$